# TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable | Keras Autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm creating an autoencoder in Keras following [this tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) and I keep getting the following error.

```
decoder = tf.keras.Model(encoded_input, decoded(input_img))
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

I believe it's something to do with not being able to use tensors in this way because of the nature of this type of object but I have some gaps in understanding of why and how to go about solving this.

Here is a minimal working example of my code:

```
# input_img input placeholder
input_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(16, 16, 1), name ="input")
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
encoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, encoded)
encoded_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
decoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, decoded(encoded_input))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras `Model` expects input & output arguments as *layers*, not tensors. The tutorial is correct - you appear to have missed a line right before `decoder =`: -- `decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]`

All together, with `decoder =` changed appropriately:

```
input_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(16, 16, 256), name ="input")
encoded   = tf.keras.layers.Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded   = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
encoder     = tf.keras.Model(input_img, encoded)

encoded_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1] # gets 'decoded' = last layer of 'autoencoder'

decoder = tf.keras.Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm getting this error now, `ValueError: A target array with shape (1000, 16, 16, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 16, 16, 256) while using as loss binary_crossentropy This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.` 
 I assume I need to reshape my tensors at some point or change the model architecture so the input and output are identical.

Comment: Autoencoders seek to reconstruct their input - thus, output & input dims must match. `Dense(256)` w/ `'sigmoid'` yields `256` output predictions - whereas your `Input` has 1 input label, i.e. last dim in `shape=`. Fix: `Input(shape=(16,16,256))`.